# Pandas plot showing error if x label is included

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my dataframe:

```
    Quantity Ordered    Price Each  Sales   Sales in $Mn Month              
 01 10903   1.811768e+06    1.822257e+06    1.82
 02 13449   2.188885e+06    2.202022e+06    2.20
 03 17005   2.791208e+06    2.807100e+06    2.81
 04 20558   3.367671e+06    3.390670e+06    3.39
 05 18667   3.135125e+06    3.152607e+06    3.15
 06 15253   2.562026e+06    2.577802e+06    2.58
 07 16072   2.632540e+06    2.647776e+06    2.65
 08 13448   2.230345e+06    2.244468e+06    2.24
 09 13109   2.084992e+06    2.097560e+06    2.10
 10 22703   3.715555e+06    3.736727e+06    3.74
 11 19798   3.180601e+06    3.199603e+06    3.20
 12 28114   4.588415e+06    4.613443e+06    4.61
```

If I run:

```
df1.plot(kind='line', x='Month', y='Sales in $Mn')
```

I get this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last) ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
 get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2888             try:
 -> 2889                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    2890             except KeyError as err:
 
 pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
 
 pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
 
 pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
 pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
 
 pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
 pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
 
 KeyError: 'Month'
 
 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
 
 KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-287-b425a6b1ccd1> in <module>
 
     ----> 1 df1.plot(kind='line', x='Month', y='Sales in $Mn', color='orange')
     
     ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         912                 if is_integer(x) and not data.columns.holds_integer():
         913                     x = data_cols[x]
     --> 914                 elif not isinstance(data[x], ABCSeries):
         915                     raise ValueError("x must be a label or position")
         916                 data = data.set_index(x)
     
     ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
        2900             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
        2901                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
     -> 2902             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
        2903             if is_integer(indexer):
        2904                 indexer = [indexer]
     
     ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
        2889                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
        2890             except KeyError as err:
     -> 2891                 raise KeyError(key) from err
        2892 
        2893         if tolerance is not None:
 
 KeyError: 'Month'
```

However, I get the correct plot if I don't include the `x` parameter, 'Month' is automatically taken on x-axis:

```
df1.plot(kind='line', y='Sales in $Mn')
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Reason is `Month` is not column, but `index`, so cannot select it by column name.

If omit parameter `x` then for `x` is used values of index, so for you working only second solution.

If check [`DataFrame.plot.line`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.line.html):

**Parameters**
**x**
**label or position, optional**
Allows plotting of one column versus another. If not specified, **the index of the DataFrame is used.**